# How to do assertions using groovy script

Tags: soapui

I'm using soapUI for test execution. I want to do contains assertion using groovy script. I want to check if a certain list of fields are present in my response or not. For that I need to use contains assertion and as per the requirement I need to do it through groovy script. Please suggest me on how to achieve it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In it's simplest form and where expectedResponse and actualResponse are both strings.

```
assert expectedResponse.contains(actualResponse) == true;
```

You will need to look up "context.expand" to obtain values from the response

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But I dont want to compare whole response, I just want two check  if 2-3 fields are present in my response or not ,since my response keeps changing everytime

Comment: The above could be applied to the whole response or one element/field/node from the response.  That's why I mentioned looking up context.expand.  I didn't want to simply the give the answer away  with letting you look it up.